# Data Source for 2012 US Congress and US Senate Elections

Tags: united-states, election, congress, data-sources

I need to find a good data source for the 2012 United States Congress and Senate elections.

I have found this: http://www.fec.gov/pubrec/fe2012/federalelections2012.shtml  The problem is that it is in a not-so-user-friendly format in Excel.  And an even harder-to-use format in PDF.

I have found the State Legislative returns in a good format at http://www.indstate.edu/polisci/klarnerpolitics.htm.  I would ideally have the same thing as this.

Any kind of CSV, Stata, etc. would be fantastic.

Any tips on where I should look?

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you need historical election data, [The Green Papers](http://www.thegreenpapers.com/G12/) is the best site to go to.  The linked page is the top-level results for 2012, and you can drill down from there.

Alternatively, if you follow the `download` link at the very bottom of that page, you can find [this google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GhJjehBDFE50I7-jhU8IaZDypcIzzZg64A92ytI-pi8/edit#gid=0) which has what appears to be *every* result for *every* race of either national or state-wide importance.  By that I mean that it includes votes for the President, US Senate, US House, Governor, Lt. Governor, and other state-wide offices (such as Attorney General) but not votes for state House or Senate seats.

Comment: @bill999 - I know this answer probably comes way too late for whatever project you were working on, but hopefully it'll help you (or someone else with a similar question) in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The [MIT Election Data and Science Lab (MEDSL)](https://electionlab.mit.edu/) maintains datasets of historical election results in `.tab` format on Harvard Dataverse.

[U.S. Senate 1976–2020](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/PEJ5QU) (state-level)

[U.S. House 1976–2020](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/IG0UN2) (district-level)

Answer (score 2):

Apologies for the 8 year lag in answer, hoping if this does not help you it will help someone with a similar question.

We have a site we are actively building that pulls and [visualizes](https://projectseldon.org/explore?country=us#politics) US Congress and Senate Election data by year. It also allows for .csv and .json exports for easy consumption.

We pull our data from [the official senate site](https://www.senate.gov/) and enrich it with
data from a few other [resources](https://theunitedstates.io/congress-legislators/legislators-historical.json), which we surface on the site UI.

The UI data is currently limited to 1960, but we have data on US House/Senate elected representatives going back all the way to 1789 and can extend the visualization (and exports) if people are interested!

Additionally, we have not yet enriched the platform with election level data (ie incumbent v candidate, or campaign/vote level data). We are looking for feedback from the community, however, and if this is something that enough people would find valuable, we would be happy to bring it in.